# Get customer object on an event

Tags: magento

I’m trying to createan observer on the following event.: 
‘sales_order_payment_pay’.

However according to magento doc 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/magento_events

I don’t have so much parameters avalaible on this event..

Do you have any idea how I could retrieve the customer object (i would need info such as customer id and customer email)?

Thanks for your feedback and anyway I wish you a nice day,

Anselme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This event does expose the payment object, so you should be able to chain off of that to get the object you want:

```
public function yourObserverFunction($event) {
    $payment = $event['payment'];
    $customer = $payment->getOrder()->getCustomer();
    // ... do something useful
}
```

Generally objects in Magento can be chained like this, and now your code doesn't rely on the event being triggered from a customer session (which is not a good assumption anyway).

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: ok that's really nice to read :) thanks for this . I did not that from getOrder() I could chain to getCustomer();

Comment: Yup, this is definitely a better method than my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Every event exposes different objects inside of the $observer object that is passed around.  In Magento you can often get a lot of stuff by referring to any number of objects that are in the request or session.  In this case there is a customer/session object (Mage_Customer_Model_Session) which has the customer attached.

```
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
  Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your feedback sdek, ok i did not know that  this object was avalaible at this time.